# Is full duplex speakerphone available as an embedded feature?

Tags: telephone

Full duplex speakerphones are clearly a complex signal processing problem, since you have to filter the device's speaker output from the microphone pickup.  But is this a feature that is presently available as self-contained embedded modules (like inertial positioning and Bluetooth)?

I'm confused because I am starting to see the feature on $40 cordless phone handsets but not on $600 smartphones.

Comment: It is available in commercial bluetooth headset chipsets

Comment: Really? There's a smartphone that *doesn't* have a speakerphone function? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @DaveTweed _Full duplex_: I.e., it doesn't have to cut the mic to transmit the sound through its speaker, or vice versa.

Comment: "How hard is ...?" is a bad question here because it requires opinions, speculation, and has no measurably correct answer.  Read the rules.

Comment: Fine, I changed the title.  Note that the question itself not only conforms, but also earned a good answer even with the "bad" title.  @OlinLathrop: I read the rules.  How about you read the contents of a question before you take review actions like that?  Furthermore "how hard is..." does have a measurably correct answer.  See the accepted answer which puts it in dollar terms.

Comment: @feetwet Just think of Olin as a wise (but sometimes cranky) guy. He's an incredible asset here, but he'll smack your wrist with his slide rule on occasion. In a nutshell, we just try to avoid questions (and titles) that might invite conjecture or opinion. Sometimes you have to word questions to avoid having them sound like shopping questions or other off-topic things. Not all moderators have time to read all new questions thoroughly, so they go by indicators such as title and first/last paragraphs, etc.

Comment: @JYelton: Thanks for the explanation.  I just checked his profile and can see Olin has made enormous contributions here!  But if _none_ of the other four reviewers who subsequently put this on hold could bother to read the question then they aren't helping matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty is doing the echo cancellation.  I suggest you look into the [Cirrus Logic CS6422 Full-Duplex Speakerphone IC](http://www.mouser.com/new/Cirrus-Logic/cirruslogic-cs6422/) which is available in single quantities for [$14.59 from Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/search/refine.aspx?Ntk=P_MarCom&Ntt=192535476).  The echo cancellation is performed by an on-board DSP.  It has a proprietary serial microcontoller interface for controlling the chip.  It comes in a 20-pin SOIC package which is not too difficult to deal with.

There is also an evaluation board but it is way expensive ($1250.00) and not in stock anyway.